# Performance of passing parameter by name vs by position

Tags: vb.net, performance

Let's say I have the following method:

```
Public Sub Foo(ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer)
{
  ...
}
```

Is there any difference in performance between the following lines?

```
Foo(1,2)
Foo(x:=1, y:=2)
Foo(y:=2, x:=1)
```

Comment: nope it compiles out the same. Though I guess the named versions take longer to compile..

Comment: What kind of performance, time to compile, time to execute, time to write?

Comment: It makes no difference, this is a detail for the compiler, not the runtime.   No matter how often you use it, you will not notice any compilation degradation.  You can't observe a microsecond.  Use whatever you prefer.

Comment: Any is Any @HansPassant. He did not ask "any noticeable"... ;)

Comment: I usually assume good faith in questions.  If you can't observe it then it of course doesn't matter and talking the OP out of a syntax option he might prefer is nonsensical advice.

Comment: I agree @HansPassant, but I have to answer the question as written. Compile time is seldom an issue these days anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute : NO

Compile : Yes - Miniscule degradation, not significant

Write   : Yes

Reading : Yes - Clarity is improved

**REASONS**

Write - Is obvious,

Execute - := is a compiler directive so compiled it ends up the same code,

```
Benchmark, 1,000,000 iterations Repeat 1,000
Index took - Average: 5.009ms Min: 5ms Max: 8ms
Named took - Average: 5.008ms Min: 5ms Max: 7ms
That is, no difference.
```

Compile - Named parameters causes a lookup of the constructor, as opposed to simple indexing. The lookups require a few more cycles.

**HOWEVER**, if you have a series of optional paramaters it comes in more useful

```
Public Sub SetSomething(A as integer, B as integer, _
                        Optional C as integer = 0, _
                        Optional D as integer = 0, _
                        Optional E as integer = 0, _
                        Optional F as integer = 0, _
                        Optional G as integer = 0, _
                        Optional H as integer = 0)

 SetSomething(X:=1,Y:=2, H:=42)
```

**Reading**

There is some benefit to using named parameters when it comes to reading your code later especially if the parameter names make sense.

For example the following line is not only clear on what is being passed and what the textboxes are supposed to contain, but you can also make a pretty good guess about what the function does.

```
 Net = Calculate(Quantity:= Double.Parse(TextBox1.Text), 
                     CostPerItem:= Double.Parse(TextBox2.Text), 
                     TaxRate:= Double.Parse(TextBox3.Text))
```

where as, this tells you nothing

```
 Net = Calculate(Double.Parse(TextBox1.Text), Double.Parse(TextBox2.Text), Double.Parse(TextBox3.Text))
```

For longer parameter list this benefit gets more helpful, especially some of the native methods that have multiple parameters that you will not remember later.

Here is another example from my own code.

```
Private Sub Refresh_Searches(ByVal DoCompressor As Boolean, ByVal DoEvaporator As Boolean, ByVal DoCondenser As Boolean, ByVal StartOver As Boolean)
```

Obviously I can call that simply by writing

```
Refresh_Searches(False, True, False, False)
```

But when I come back in six months, or in my case.. 6 minutes, it's gibberish without using the mouse. The below is much better even though it takes so much longer to write.

```
Refresh_Searches(DoCompressor:=False, _
                 DoCondenser:=True, _
                 DoEvaporator:=False, _
                 StartOver:=False)
```

Comment: If you had enough of them u might notice... but it's small.. question was ANY.. @Pikoh

Comment: Thanks for the extremely detailed answer!

Comment: +1 I was about to do the question "Passing arguments by position vs by name" but this one already answers everything I wanted to confirm.